# How to consume SSRS Report which has SbuReport from Web Application using ReportExecutionService class

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

My Web Application consume SSRS Report deployed in report server and it uses ReportExecutionService Class. It works fine.

If I have subreport, I am calling Main Report and set parameter to main only but it does not return the output.

How to consume SSRS Report which has SbuReport from Web Application using ReportExecutionService class in c#. it works if the report has no sub reports. For sub report what need to be done.

The following code is consuming a sigle report.

```
ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue[] parameters = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue[tparams.Count];
int i = 0;

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in tparams)
{

    parameters[i] = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue();
    parameters[i].Name = entry.Key.ToString();
    parameters[i].Value = entry.Value.ToString();
    i = i + 1;
}

ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionService();
rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUserName, strpwd, strDomainName);
//Prepare Render arguments
rs.LoadReport(tstrRDLReportNameWithPath, historyID);
rs.SetExecutionParameters(tparameters, "en-us");
results = rs.Render(tstrFormat, deviceInfo, out extension,
```